# All post attachments in gallery grid to full screen slideshow?

Tags: jquery, attachments, twitter-bootstrap

Using the default wp gallery for displaying the attachments. All attachments for the specific post in full screen slideshow when click on image. I am using also Bootstrap frond end framework. Possible with carouse?

Comment: What is your actual question here? :)

Comment: How actually to trigger that carousel to work for post attachments?

Comment: Do you know (form reading Bootstrap carousel documentation) which markup changes are required or if it would work with arbitrary markup? What had you tried? What didn't work out of what you had tried?

Comment: Pretty new to jquery and javascript. I did nothing, because I have no idea where to start from. Maybe I should trigger bootstrap carousel with click on image.

Comment: I would advise to study carousel component in general (ask more JS-specific questions about it on [so] if needed) then, before trying to deal with it in WordPress.

Comment: Isn't there a native functions for this action? Or some plugins? I'ts a lot of information for a basic jquery user like me.